# Preencher array dinamicamente

Tags: php

Galera, preciso de ajuda. Tenho a seguinte estrutura fixa em php:

```
'labels' => array('Jan','Fev','Mar')......
```

Porem quero preencher esses valores internos do array dinamicamente, ou seja vou buscar no banco certos meses aleatórios e usar ali dentro. Porem tento fazer assim:

```
$meu_array = array();
// preencho o array

'labels' => array($meu_array);
```

Porem não funciona. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

Se você fizer o array correto com os dados que esta vindo do banco, é pra funcionar igual seu exemplo dos meses. Fiz um exemplo aqui mais ou menos.

```
$a = array('labels' => array('jav', 'fev', 'marc'));
$my_array = array('jav', 'fev', 'marc');
$new_array = array('labels' => $my_array);
```

> Ficará assim:

```
Array
(
    [labels] => Array
    (
        [0] => jav
        [1] => fev
        [2] => marc
        )

    )

segundo array 
Array
(
    [labels] => Array
    (
        [0] => jav
        [1] => fev
        [2] => marc
        )

    )
```

Viu igualzinho. Se você não está conseguindo acessar seu segundo array nos índices é porque não está preenchendo corretamente.

Sempre verifique como o array está ficando com var_dump, print_r se não está conseguindo acessar um conteúdo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um array dinâmico usando "[]":

```
$array['labels'][] = 'Jan';
$array['labels'][] = 'Mar';
$array['labels'][] = 'Fev';

var_dump($array);
```

resultado:

```
array (size=1)
  'labels' => 
     array (size=3)
       0 => string 'Jan' (length=3)
       1 => string 'Mar' (length=3)
       2 => string 'Fev' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando vou preencher array dinamicamente faço em forma de matriz, que transferir a tabela do banco diretamente pra array:

```
$new_table = array();

  for($a = 0; $a < 2; $a++){
  //Avança as linhas
  $new_table[$a][$b] = $varbanco['Meses'];
  $new_table[$a][$b+1] = $varbanco['Ano'];
  $new_table[$a][$b+2] = $varbanco['Dia'];
}
```

CLaro que deve haver uma maneira mais simples, mas essa forma possibilita adicionar informações futuras caso seja necessario